# AngularJS import issue

Tags: html, angularjs

If I run a simple AngularJS (W3Schools example) application using a single html file it works properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<div ng-view>

</div>

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#banana">Banana</a>
<a href="#tomato">Tomato</a>

<p>Click on the links to change the content.</p>

<p>The HTML shown in the ng-view directive are written in the template property of the $routeProvider.when method.</p>

<script> 

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
    })
    .when("/banana", {
        template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
    });
});

app.controller('mainController',function($scope){


});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I divide the routing from the html file it does not work anymore:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<div ng-view>

</div>

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#banana">Banana</a>
<a href="#tomato">Tomato</a>

<p>Click on the links to change the content.</p>

<p>The HTML shown in the ng-view directive are written in the template property of the $routeProvider.when method.</p>


<script src="Controller/routing.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Controller/routing.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
    })
    .when("/banana", {
        template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
    });
});

app.controller('mainController',function($scope){


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the file is incorrect. Try:

`<script src="/Controller/routing.js"></script>`

Relative path should start with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi DistribuzioneGaussiana,
If you check your console you will see the browser fails to load the angular-route file from the cdn you have provided.Add http: the cdn source,make it -  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js 
and it will work.

Comment: Did you add this - 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>` in your index.html file ?

Comment: I have tried. But it can't be the error because when I put the html and the js code (importing ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js) in just one file my simple application works properly.

Comment: I replicated the same code and structure you mentioned. It is working fine for me after doing the change. Are you getting any error in the console?